# Concurrency Handelling in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: ios, azure, azure-storage

I am an iOS developer & currently working on Azure Mobile service. I am using Azure iOS client SDK. I have query on concurrency model in Azure as I found below links

[Link 1](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/managing-concurrency-in-microsoft-azure-storage-2/)

[Link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-concurrency)

But I am unable to understand how I should manage concurrency from iOS app as I am not using SQLite for database.

Comment: Its not clear what question you are asking.    Are you having trouble choosing between an optimistic, pessimistic or last-writer wins strategy?

Comment: @Burt_Harris yes, I am having problem in selection. Please guide me.